# maven error using tripleplay and react SNAPSHOTs

Tags: maven, playn

I switched from tripleplay and react from 1.0 and 1.1 to 1.1-SNAPSHOT and 1.2-SNAPSHOT respectively, to be able to use the latest code from git (such as AbsoluteLayout)

now when I try to package the game for HTML5 using

`mvn clean package`

I get:

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.threerings:react:jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.threerings:tripleplay:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project h4ck1t-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.jengibre:h4ck1t-core:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.threerings:react:jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT, com.threerings:tripleplay:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.threerings:react:jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT in http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of forplay-legacy has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I tried adding `-U` to force it for updates, with no effect

My pom uses PlayN version 1.0.3

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snapshot releases are not available from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.threerings%22), only released versions.

You could try and find a snapshot repository (if it exists) and then add it into the repositories section of your POM.

Comment: what I did was go to the playn, react and tripleplay projects (in that order) and execute `mvn clean install` so that build the jars and placed them on my local repo

Comment: Indeed, but I prefer it since I can build new snapshots myself after pulling changes from the remote git repo, instead of depending on nightlies or something like that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In playn-samples project, edit core/pom.xml and get rif of -SNAPSHOT for the tripleplay dependency.
1.1 has been released to the mvn main repo.